# How to export dictionary as CSV using Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I am having problems exporting certain items in a dictionary to CSV. I can export 'name' but not 'images' (the image URL).

This is an example of part of my dictionary:

```
new = [{ "name" : "peter", "picture" : "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F33500665%2F25911657759%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C581%2C6000%2C3000&s=bfaa2901b8c906a66c51563d15c6df12"},
{"name" : "jim" , "picture" : "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F32935536%2F10115879927%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C40%2C624%2C312&s=c67e995e83234ab460707ac21f3541f8"}]
```

EDIT (I made a mistake with the naming as was what pointed out. It seems to work now after updating it).

And this is the code I have written (which works for 'name' but not 'picture'):

```
import csv

test = []

for document in new:
    event_obj = {}

    # Get name
    event_obj['name'] = document['name']

    # Get images
    event_obj['picture'] = document['picture']

    test.append(event_obj)

# Create CSV file
with open('Eventbrite_events.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     fields = ['name', 'picture']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
     writer.writeheader()
     for x in test:
         writer.writerow(x)
print(csvfile)
```

Comment: check naming images > picture

Comment: Seems to work now. Thanks @Anar Bayramov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `new` list contains dictionaries with the key `picture` but you were trying to access one called `images`.

```
import csv

new = [
    { "name" : "peter", "picture" : "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F33500665%2F25911657759%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C581%2C6000%2C3000&s=bfaa2901b8c906a66c51563d15c6df12"},
    {"name" : "jim" , "picture" : "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F32935536%2F10115879927%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C40%2C624%2C312&s=c67e995e83234ab460707ac21f3541f8"}]

test = []

for document in new:
    event_obj = {}

    # Get name
    event_obj['name'] = document['name']

    # Get images
    event_obj['images'] = document['picture']

    test.append(event_obj)

# Create CSV file
with open('Eventbrite_events.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fields = ['name', 'images']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(test)
```

You could also make use of `writerows()` to write all the rows in one go.

This would give you a CSV file as follows:

```
name,images
peter,https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F33500665%2F25911657759%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C581%2C6000%2C3000&s=bfaa2901b8c906a66c51563d15c6df12
jim,https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F32935536%2F10115879927%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C40%2C624%2C312&s=c67e995e83234ab460707ac21f3541f8
```

---

You could also avoid building `test` as follows as an alternative way to rename your entry:

```
import csv

new = [
    {"name" : "peter", "picture" : "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F33500665%2F25911657759%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C581%2C6000%2C3000&s=bfaa2901b8c906a66c51563d15c6df12"},
    {"name" : "jim" , "picture" : "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F32935536%2F10115879927%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C40%2C624%2C312&s=c67e995e83234ab460707ac21f3541f8"}]

# Create CSV file
with open('Eventbrite_events.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fields = ['name', 'images']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in new:
        row['images'] = row.pop('picture')
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas` is more suitable for your question.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pf.DataFrame(list_of_dict)

df.columns = ["name", "image or picture"]

df.to_csv("test.csv", index=0)
```